# Laravel - Using model's static function in blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to use model's static functions in view? What I am trying to do is fetch booth name while I have the booth ID in the view.

```
{{booth::find($voter->boothId)->name}}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @AdreAstrian, ErrorException (E_ERROR) Class 'booth' not found

Comment: What is the namespaced name of the `booth` class?

Comment: This doesn't belong into a view, use repositories to maintain your code, BAD!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, but class name must be full name for example `App\booth`

```
{{App\booth::find($voter->boothId)->name}}
```

Or you can add class alias in app.config

```
'aliases' => [
    ....
    'booth' => App\boot::class \\ your class namespace
],
```

and in .blade use

```
{{booth::find($voter->boothId)->name}}
```

But for good practice you must be check `booth::find($voter->boothId)` null or instance of `boot` model 
For example

```
@php($booth = booth::find($voter->boothId))
{{$booth ? $booth->name : 'some content'}}
```